# Deprecating fields in django model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, deprecation-warning, class-attributes

I'm normalizing a database associated with a Django project and will be moving fields to different tables. As part of the implementation process, I'd like to throw a deprecation warning to my colleagues if they attempt to use the old attributes after adding the new tables before I actually remove the columns.

```
class Asset(Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    part_number = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True) # this will be a redundant column to be deprecated
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True) # this will be a redundant column to be deprecated
    # other database fields as attributes and class methods
```

My understanding is that I would need to add something along the lines of `warnings.warn('<field name> is deprecated', DeprecationWarning)` somewhere in the class, but where would I add it?

Comment: You could change the fields to properties and handle the warning there, and return the appropriate value if possible.

Comment: A possible solution: https://shezadkhan.com/aliasing-fields-in-django/

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps you could use Django's [system check framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/checks/) (introduced in Django 1.7).

Some interesting examples, using the system-check-framework for deprecation of *custom* fields, are provided in the [migrations docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#considerations-when-removing-model-fields).

It seems you can also use this approach to mark *standard* fields on your model.
Applied to the example from the original post, the following works for me (tested in Django 3.1.6).

```
class Asset(Model):
    ...
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)  
    company.system_check_deprecated_details = dict(
        msg='The Asset.company field has been deprecated.',
        hint='Use OtherModel.other_field instead.',
        id='fields.W900',  # pick a unique ID for your field.
    )
    ...
```

See the [system check API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/checks/) for more detailed information, e.g. about the "unique ID".

The following warning will then show, whenever you call `runserver`, `migrate`, or other commands, as mentioned [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/checks/#module-django.core.checks):

```
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
myapp.Asset.company: (fields.W900) The Asset.company field has been deprecated.
    HINT: Use OtherModel.other_field instead.
```

Also nice to know (from the docs):

> ... For performance reasons, checks are not run as part of the WSGI stack that is used in deployment. ...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `django_deprication.DeprecatedField`

```
pip install django-deprecation
```

then use like this

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name = DeprecatedField('title')
```

https://github.com/openbox/django-deprecation

Comment: Do you know perchance if this works with conversion to a ForeignKey?  It looks like it should, but curious if you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar to this - turn the field into a property and handle the warning there. Note that this will still break any queries you make that filter on the field - just helps with accessing the attribute from instances.

```
class NewAsset(Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)

class Asset(Model):
    @property
    def model(self):
        log.warning('Stop using this')
        return NewAsset.model
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't risk breaking any existing functionality just yet